# Discord.py / Error: Ignoring exception in on_message

Tags: python, discord.py

HELLO I am using visual studio/python and trying to make a discord bot. No matter what I do I encounter this error.                                                                                                                                                                                [Ignoring exception in on_message/Traceback (most recent call last):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWL43.png)

the program runs my function, accompanied with the error, in visual studio but it does not appear it in the discord chat where I write my message.

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   
   if message.author == client.user:
       return
 
   if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
     
     await message.channel.send('write a message:')
     msg = await client.wait_for("message")
     parameter = msg.content
         
     await message.channel.send(defname(parameter)) ```                                                       

EDIT: ookay the problem was in my FUNCTION, which was ending on print(), instead of return ""
````

Comment: [**PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: Can you send full code?

Comment: FIXED the problem was in my FUNCTION, which was ending on print(), instead of return ""

Answer (score 0):

You may not have instantiated the Discord client but just imported the client from discord.py

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
   
   if message.author == client.user:
       return
 
   if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
     
     await message.channel.send('write a message:')
     msg = await client.wait_for("message")
     parameter = msg.content
         
     await message.channel.send(defname(parameter))
 

 client.run('your token here')
```

Comment: thanks, my question was really poor. so the problem was in my FUNCTION, which was ending on print(), instead of return "".